# How to sort a nested UL list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a nested UL list and i need to sort all elements in that on click of up and down. up will be ascending order and down will be descending order. Html code start from here-

```
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="contan">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="up"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="down"></span>
        <ul id="test">
      <li class="sortable">First item</li>
      <li class="sortable">second item
      <ul> <li >Third item</li>
      <li>Forth item
    </li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
          </div>
      </body>
```

Sorting ascending order should be:

- . First item
- . Second item
- . Forth item
- . Third item

Will anyone help me out how to write a javascript or jquery function?

Comment: *Will anyone help me out how to write a javascript or jquery function?*  Why not? Please show your attempt first and share a working snippet demonstrating a specific issue that you are facing.

Comment: function javascript(){
//"this is a javascript function"
}
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#up").on("click", function(){


// "this a jquery function"
})
});
This is what i am doing
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#up").on("click", function(){
         $('.sortable').not(".sortable li").sort(function(a, b){
            return $('a', a).text() > $('a', b).text();
        }).appendTo(".current");
});
      }); This is how i can sort the parent but i need to append the child also in sorted order to the same parent

Answer (score 0):

Below code is the basic idea for sorting an array in ascending & descending order. This code is just for displaying a list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Click the button to sort the array in ascending order.</h3>
<button onclick="Ascend()"> Asc</button>
<p id="asc"></p>

<h3>Click button to sort the array in descending order.</h3>
<button onclick="Descend()">Desc</button>
<p id="desc"></p>

<script>
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;

function Ascend() {
    points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    document.getElementById("asc").innerHTML = points;
}
function Descend() {
    points.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = points;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```